# Hyphen in FQDN not working with Apache 2.4.18 on Ubuntu?

Tags: apache

I am a little confused on this one.  I am trying to add a new site to my server which is not that unusual, the issue is this one has a "-" in the FQDN and it seems like Apache is not liking that in the ServerName field

Here is my apache config file. If I remove the "-" from ServerName bingo it works, if I leave it in, the site is skipped and traffic is routed to the default site.

Note: I am not getting any errors, everything starts up and all of the other sites work -- it is only this one site that is having an issue.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName eye-catcher.com
        ServerAlias www.eye-catcher.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@eye-catcher.com
        DocumentRoot /var/lib/wordpress/sites/eyecatcher

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/wp/eyecatcher-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/wp/eyecatcher-access.log vhost_combined

        <Directory /var/lib/wordpress/sites/eyecatcher>
                Options None FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Require all granted

                # BEGIN WordPress
                <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                        RewriteEngine On
                        RewriteBase /
                        RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
                        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                        RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
                </IfModule>
                # END WordPress
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So what am I missing?  I feel like it is something simple -- just not sure what.